# Extracting Excel sheet's style and applying it on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I've been looking around, however, it seems that this question was not asked yet.

Is there a way to get Excel's sheet style format and apply it on a Pandas DataFrame, respecing the shape of the DataFrame and replicating completely?

Example:

[image]

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** While going through style documentation I've noticed that there is:

```
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
EasyStyler = Styler.from_custom_template("templates", "myhtml.tpl")
HTML(EasyStyler(df3).render(table_title="Another Title"))
```

After exporting Excel to HTML I've attempted to perform this, however, was unsuccessful.

Comment: Where are you trying to put this? In a web page, exported as an image, back into a spreadsheet, printed to a console...?

Comment: No reading an excel and excel formats and converting to a styled pandas dataframe is not possible.

Comment: @camille trying to apply it on df on jupyter-notebook

Comment: It's probably not _impossible_, but there might not be any library that support this. It's a very niche use case, and excel has a very complex styling feature set, including conditional formatting etc. You can take a look at what you can do with openpyxl. Pandas will only extract data from excel files, and has support for writing styles, but not for reading styles from excel. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

Comment: It would require setting up everything from scratch, but looking for something that would extract and then apply the style on df either in the notebook or export xlsx with that style. @HåkenLid

Comment: @AkmalSoliev What are the rules for applying the style ? eg max value ? by values range ?

Comment: No rules, there is no conditional formatting, it is just simply taking the style from excel and applying it on top of pandas DataFrame
@EBDS

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not pretty good with styling, I think a better option would be `openpyxl`

That's if you want to save it as an excel file, then you can define the styles with `openpyxl`

If you want to display a dataframe with styles, that's not possible.

```
from openpyxl import styles
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
```

Comment: Hey, I've already looked into that and unfortunately doesn't solve my issue, seems that I need to create CSS styling from scratch for DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with pandas specifically. You would have to get to the reading of the raw excel data and parse the xml-ish format that it comes in and then recreate the styling you want.